# Переадресация robots.txt на php в nginx

Tags: php, nginx, centos, redirect, robots.txt

Есть сервер CentOS с nginx.
Нужно сделать динамический robots.txt.
Для этого сделал **robots.php** и переадресацию на него для **robots.txt**,
но если вызывать site.ru/robots.txt то этот robots.php не выполняется а выдается как текст.
Если вызвать site.ru/robots.php то все работает.
Переадресация в nginx такая:

```
location /robots.txt { alias /home/xxx/web/site.ru/public_html/robots.php; }
```

как заставить этот код выполняться?

Answer (score 2):

Либо так:

```
location = /robots.txt {
    rewrite ^ /robots.php;
}
```

либо добавить в ваш `location` все директивы по обработке php-файлов (начиная с `fastcgi_pass`).

Мне кажется, что `rewrite` проще.